# ORA-1882 when attempting to use daylight savings time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp-with-timezone

We receive a file from an external provider.  One of the columns contains a timestamp in the form "05/01/2014 09:25:41 AM EDT".  I am trying to insert this into a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column with the following SQL:

`INSERT INTO table VALUES (to_timestamp_tz('05/01/2014 09:25:41 AM EDT', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZR TZD'));`

That is when I get `ORA-1882: timezone region not found`.  I've also tried specifying this like

`INSERT INTO table VALUES (to_timestamp_tz('05/01/2014 09:25:41 AM EST EDT', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZR TZD'));`

but then I get `ORA-1857: not a valid time zone`.

Anyone have an idea how I can insert this?  We are running Oracle 11.2.0.3.  I can see in `v$timezone_names` that EST and EDT both appear to be valid tzabbrev for tzname 'America/New York'.

EDIT:

It appears that if I substitute EST5EDT for EDT (and CST6CDT, MST7MDT, and PST8PDT for CST, MST, and PST, respectively) , I can get the behavior I need.  The problem with this is that I need to know what these substitutions are in advance so I can code around them.  I still need to know how to handle potential daylight savings time issues with other timezones.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO TAB VALUES (to_timestamp_tz('05/01/2014 08:25:41 AM ,America/New_York', 
                                        'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS.FF AM TZR:TZD'));`

Comment: This is requiring that I know the region associated with the time zone.  All I am getting in the file is EST, EDT, PST, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The short names are not possible, because they are ambiguous. `ECT` for example may be used for "European Central Time", "Ecuador Time" or "Eastern Caribbean Time". Thus you have to use the long names, e.g. `America/New_York` or the UTC+/-hh:mi notation.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding it then. Because when I do something like this:`to_timestamp_tz('05/01/2014 09:25:41 AM EST', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM TZR')`, I properly get UTC -5:00, so it clearly knows I am referring to Eastern Standard.  I figured adding EDT after that would tell the database that this is also a daylight savings time area.  I guess I'll have to come up with something else.